# Persist session when accessing site with and without www

Tags: php, session

I have logged in my site using the url `http://www.example.com` and can go to the authenticated page `http://www.example.com/dashboard`

But when I change the url to `http://example.com/dashboard` (no www), I am redirecting back to login page.

How can I fix it so that the one login session works for both domains?

Comment: @JohnC OP is not asking for redirect, so it's not a duplicate. Redirecting is the best solution, though. Also for SEO purposes.

Comment: That's fair enough @GolezTrol, there are a number of solutions in the related questions to the right. I've retracted the vote.